# what is the connection error when transferring Moodle to localhost?

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to run moodle on localhost, an error appears - what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ?
code config.php -renamed it to your localhost, made the connection

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysql';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodledb';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = '';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => 3306,
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'C:/Server/data/htdocs/moodle/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:/Server/data/htdocs/moodle/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

[error/generalexceptionmessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFG2I.png)

The code that was on the server in the config:

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodledb';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'moodleedu';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'moodleedpas';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => 3306,
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://moodle.com';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

Also, the question is where can I more specifically look at the list of errors in moodle - where does it write data?

Comment: "wwwroot" is a URL in the server config but a local path in the local config... maybe?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz changed: $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost:3000/moodle/moodle/';. The error still remained

Comment: @PredictorLibrus-Quattuor you need to but the full URL prefixed with `HTTP/HTTPs` of moodle server, could you show the errors?